# How to find ID not in the master ID table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, asp-classic

Let's say I have a master table for **Products**, and another table which keeps lists of **ProductIDs**.

```
  Table name: Products  
 --------------------
 ProductID, Title, Price  
       1, Title 1, 12.00  
       2, Title 2, 15.00  
       4, Title 4, 11.50  
       8, Title 8, 13.89  
       11, Title 11, 12.00  

     Table name: ListOfProducts  
      --------------------------
       SomeID, ProductIDs  

         34, 4,8,1  
         35, 8,10,2
```

Now, you can see that in the table `ListOfProducts`, record with `SomeID=35`, the list of products is `8,10,2`. How can I use SQL to quickly find out the invalid `ProductID 10`, since it is not in the master table Products?

My program is actually in classic **ASP** (legacy), and the database is in MS SQL. I can do a loop in ASP to iterate through the records in `ListOfProducts`, but how do I use a quick SQL to find any invalid `ProductID`? In this case, when the program loop to record `35`, the script should return `ProductID 10`.

This looks really simple. But I just couldn't think of a good solution. Can this be done?
Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: read `MySQL FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: I am actually using MS SQL. Is there a similar function in MS SQL? Anyway, I am new to this, some code example would be great. Thanks.

Comment: MS-SQL does not have a native split function, as far as I know.

Comment: Read this article by [@Aaron Bertrand](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand). That's all you need: **[Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)** But only until you normalize the table. I suggect you don't delay taking that path.

Comment: This would be a LOT easier with a normalized database :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not store IDs as a comma seperated list, this seems more like a many-to-many relation. You should have a table like:

```
SomeID | ProductID
-------------------
34     | 4
34     | 8
34     | 1
35     | 8
35     | 10
35     | 2
```

If you really must use a comma seperated list then you need to create some sort of [split function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql%20split%20function)

Comment: Unfortunately, the ProductIDs are currently stored in a list.

Comment: That's no problem, parse the list and put it into a table.  Don't proceed with a bad design just because 'it was done that way' unless of course there is absolutely no other option.  No DB admin will suggest you store lists in a single field.  What you're seeing is a bad-design band-aid!  A quick fix for poor normalization.

Comment: I really have no choice but to continue to use this because this is part of a bigger program.